# Trouble Using the OR | operator in PHP preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Working with the following strings which are generated via UI but shown twice to show possible variants;

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the LE300 tractor';
```

or

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the LE 300 tractor';
```

or

```
$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the 300 series tractor';
```

I'm wanting to extract the LE300, LE 300 or just the 300 (assuming a visitor didn't enter LE)

As such I created a preg_match() to pull these bits out.

With the following code I can extract LE300 or LE 300 but not just 300.

```
preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{1,3} ?\d\d\d? ?[a-zA-Z]{0,1}? (?=\s|$)/', $string, $matches);
```

I've tried;

```
preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{1,3} ?\d\d\d? ?[a-zA-Z]{0,1}? ?| [0-9]{2,3} (?=\s|$)/', $Title, $matches);
```

and

```
preg_match('/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]{1,3} ?\d\d\d? ?[a-zA-Z]{0,1}? ?| \d\d\d? (?=\s|$)/', $Title, $matches);
```

but no matter what I do I can't extract a 2 or 3 digit number standing by itself.

If anyone has any ideas on how to correct this, I'd be most appreciative if you'd share with me

Comment: Why don't you just change `{1,3}` to `{0,3}`, so that there can be zero letters before the number?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be far more simple than that.  Essentially, you're looking for possibly 2 capital letters followed by an optional space then 3 digits.  This accomplishes that:

```
preg_match('/((?:[A-Z]{2})?\s*\d{3})/', $string1, $matches);
```

If you want to allow lowercase le then you can do:

```
preg_match('/((?:[A-Za-z]{2})?\s*\d{3})/', $string1, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If rest of the string is constant then it can be very simple.

```
preg_match('/The quick brown fox jumped over the (.*) tractor/', $string1, $matches);
```